# Bootstrap tabs: Open tab and scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to link the Messages tab and once user clicks on that link it should open the tab and scroll.

The scroll function is working but how can I set the tab as active?

```
$('a.js-link-scroll').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var that = this;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(that).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/mn83jsa2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.js-link-scroll').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   $('#myTabs .active').removeClass('active');//remove all active classes
   $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').parent().addClass('active');//add the active class to the #message tab
    var that = this;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(that).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jvhofaxz/